# Starting a Foreground Service in Activity

Tags: java, android, eclipse, oop, notifications

How can I start a service in Activity?

I tried to call:

```
Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, getText(R.string.app_name),System.currentTimeMillis());
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, getText(R.string.app_name),getText(R.string.app_name), pendingIntent);
    startForeground(1, notification);
```

However, it "Cannot resolve method 'startforeground(int, android.app.Notification)'"

What do I do to call startForeground? I tried getApplicationContext() to no avail.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> How can I start a service in Activity?

Call `startService()`.

> However, it "Cannot resolve method 'startforeground(int, android.app.Notification)'"

`startForeground()` is a method on `Service`. Your `Service` will need to call `startForegrond()` upon itself (e.g., in the service's `onCreate()`).

Comment: So I need a separate class that manages the notification? And it has to extend service?

Comment: @WayWay: All of the code that you have in your question belongs in a `Service`. More importantly, that code should only be run when you have a `Service` that needs to have foreground priority. Foreground services can be detrimental to the user experience (e.g., causing your process to tie up system RAM). Only use them when the user will value the reason why your service is running and why you have called `startForeground()` on the service.

Comment: Thank you, I understand the mechanisms of the Service now.